# Largest populated area without cars

Tags: automobiles, factoids

I would like to visit somewhere with no cars. What are the largest inhabited regions with no automobiles? (Emergency vehicles are allowed.)

Comment: I doubt there are any. A modern society does not just use vehicles for emergencies. What about trash collection, maintenance etc... There are quite a few places in Europe that do not permit private cars, but they nevertheless have lots of vehicles...

Comment: I don't know whether its the largest, but (other than some large car parks and the port area on the edge of the island) there are no cars in Venice in Italy, not even emergency vehicles or maintenance / trash collection etc. Everything is done by boat or handcart.

Comment: It is a duplicate, since it links to a list of car-free areas not limited to islands. Picking the best-known, Mackinac Island, it has a total car ban except emergency and service vehicles.

Comment: Although Venice meets the theoretical requirements, it is an odd case because it has buses, taxis, private vehicles, traffic lights, all the stuff you would expect to find in a busy city center.